# Mpdf loaded once then not worked

Tags: php, mpdf

I am currently trying Mpdf, installed it using composer and created a simple code. Here it is

```
<?php 
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML("<h1 style='color:red'>Hello world!</h1>");
$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

It successfully loaded once then it doesnt load more. I am loading it via XAMPP.
Thankyou so much. Hope someone helps me.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the part where it actually writes to a file

for example, this is the html

```
$html = '<table width="60%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Empid</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                   <td>320800</td>
                   <td>61</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>';

//save the file put which location you need folder/filname
$mpdf->Output("phpflow.pdf", 'F');


//out put in browser below output function
$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: you can follow complete guide on here: https://www.phpflow.com/php/create-pdf-file-using-mpdf-php/